# Nginx custom 301 rewrite

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

I am struggling to find how to write this scenario 301 redirect to nginx:

```
https://mydomain/$
```

to be converted

```
https://mydomain/en_us/$
```

Actually I need to add **"en_us"** just after **mydomain** and just before my dynamic
urls

What I tried is this:

```
location /
          {
             rewrite ^(/.*)/ $1/en_us/$ last;
          }
```

But no luck

Any help please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu I updated the question

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question. Please also add what does "no luck" mean. What command did you try, what was the expected result and what was the actual result?

Comment: @G.G. A similar question and solution is provided at https://serverfault.com/a/1122830/102173 . Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this:

```
rewrite "^/(?!admin|en_us|stripe)(.*)" /en_us/$1 permanent;
```

Inside `()`

you can put whatever word contained in url which needs to be excluded.

Also if you use nginx as proxy don't forget to use:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

So the port won't transfered in the redirect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).