# Nginx Redirection Rule

Tags: nginx, redirection

I am trying to redirect

- `https://example.com/1001/def.txt` -> `https://example.com/1001/1/def.txt`
- `https://example.com/1001/*` -> `https://example.com/1001/1/*`

```
location /2023/ {
  if ($request_uri ~* "/2023/(.*)") {
    return 302 /1/$2 break;
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, whenever I am trying to match the path `/1001/` and redirect it to the destination path, that also contains `1001` in `/1001/1/`, the request goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: are you sure the location specified in the configuration is correct? you have 2023 while in the example you have 1001

Answer (score 1):

To prevent infinite loop, you need to use a rewrite condition that only matches the original URL and not the rewritten one. You can achieve the desired redirection using the following **nginx** configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /1001/ {
        if ($request_uri !~ "^/1001/1/") {
            rewrite ^/1001/(.*)$ /1001/1/$1 permanent;
        }
        # Your other server configuration
    }
}
```

This configuration uses the if directive to add a condition that the URL should not contain **/1001/1/**. The **rewrite** directive is then used to redirect requests to **/1001/** to **/1001/1/**. The **$1** in the destination URL captures the portion of the URL that matched the **(.*)** pattern. The **permanent** flag indicates that this should be a permanent redirect.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Simple too. I was wondering for an (easy) answer for a similar question posted recently... https://serverfault.com/q/1122268/102173

Answer (score 0):

You can try following setup:

```
location ~ ^/1001/[1-9]/ {
    # block configuration
}

location ~ ^/1001/(.*) {
    return 302 /1001/1/$1;
}
```

The order of `location` blocks is significant: nginx uses the first matching regular expression location for processing the request. You can adjust the regular expression in first `location` block to more accurately match your desired target URL structure.